# How to get information from a Get-Request

Tags: python, java, get

I'm writing a service in Java. Which sends a get request to the server. I store the URL of my contacts in it (I hope)

```
public static void sendGET(**String tmp**) throws IOException {
        URL obj = new URL(GET_URL);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setReadTimeout(5000);
        con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
}
```

Also I have a Python server,

```py
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
from urllib.parse import urlparse

hostName = "192.168.31.225"
serverPort = 8080

class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        print(self.requestline)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<html><head><title>https://pythonbasics.org</title></head>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>Request: %s</p>" % self.path, "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<body>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>This is an example web server.</p>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("</body></html>", "utf-8"))


    def do_POST(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        content_len = int(self.headers.get('Content-Length'))
        post_body = self.rfile.read(content_len)
        self.pars_args(post_body)

    def pars_args(self,msg):
        msg = msg.decode('UTF-8')
        msg.split('\n')
        print(msg)
```

I would really like pars_args to return at least something from def do_GET. I know that in Get in Java I store my contacts in the URL. But I’m not smart enough to see them in Python on the Server :((

pars_args was now set for Post requests...

I know that I need to decode the data back in order to output it in print(msg) or at least in a Get request so that it appears on my server, for example, but I just can’t get the data

I tried to rewrite pars_args for do_GET but it didn’t work... I don’t understand

I took the get request code from [here](https://www.8host.com/blog/otpravka-http-zaprosov-get-i-post-v-java/)

Comment: How? -> "I store my contacts in the URL"

Comment: @LMC `        HttpURLConnectionExample connection = new HttpURLConnectionExample();
        String tmp = readContacts(getApplicationContext());
        String contacts = tmp + end;
        tmp = URLEncoder.encode(contacts, "utf-8"); `                     
tmp variable, which is also used in void sendGET

Comment: so url is something like `host/path?key=val&key=val`? Still unclear. Questions are expected to provide a [mcve]

Comment: my variable tmp contains +%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0+*525%23%0A                                                                                                     its Russian language sorry(